Can not use $rename to rename property of documents
I have a mongoose Schema and I would like to rename a certain property named 'template' to 'document'.
If I would first change name of the property from 'template' to 'document' in the Schema and than try to use updateMany, nothing happens.
var results = await Document.updateMany(
            { templateType: {$exists: true}},
            { $rename: { templateType: "documentType" } }
        );

When updateMany runs, results.modifiedCount is greated than 0, but documents still all have templateType when I view them in compass.
Thanks,

Do the updateMany first then change the field name in your schema.

This question is similar to: Rename field in mongoose. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
